# Appearances of an element in a family of subsets

Tags: combinatorics

If $S=\{x_1, x_2, x_3 ...x_n\}$ and I write out each *k*-subset of $S$, how many times will I write $x_1$?

Comment: Choose the other $k-1$ elements from the other $n-1$ elements.

Comment: No I did not, thank you very much Pp..